# Why aren't my JSON values appearing in my WCF operation?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having problems getting values to my WCF operation from my JQuery code. I have a WCF operation with the following declaration:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public ResultList<MyResult> FindResults(string latitude, string longitude)
{
  // latitude and longitude are always "0" here.
}
```

My JQuery code looks like the following:

```
var latitude = GetLatitude();
var longitude = GetLongitude();
alert(latitude + ", " + longitude);

var json = { "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude };
$.ajax({
  url: "/services/myService.svc/FindResults",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: json2string(json),
  dataType: "json",
  success: findResultsCompleted,
});
```

When I look in Fiddler, I receive a 200 status code as expected. The request header shows:

```
GET /services/myService.svc/FindResults?{"latitude":33.041599,"longitude":-119.298798}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are latitude and longitude always 0 in the operation code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` requests expect the parameters like `?Param=Value`

You could switch your `OperationContract` to `WebInvoke` and your JS service call to `POST`

Or if you want to stick with `GET` you can just remove the `stringify` call and jQuery should take care of making the `GET` parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If they're strings why isn't the json in quotes?

```
"latitude":33.041599,"longitude":-119.298798
```

as opposed to

```
"latitude":"33.041599","longitude":"-119.298798"
```

Can you either change your json to enclose the values in quotes or change your operation to accept `double`s?

Comment: when I wrap the values in quotes, the latitude and longitude parameters become null in the operation code.